# Uploading data from Amazon S3 to Amazon Cloudsearch error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudsearch

I am trying to upload the data from Amazon S3 Bucket to Amazon CloudSearch domain using AWS CLI. When I try to execute the command

```
cs-import-documents -d mydomain --source s3://mybucket/myobject.json
```

I get the following error :

> AWS authentication requires a valid Date or x-amz-date header (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied)

When I try to use the command

```
aws cloudsearchdomain upload-documents
```

and pass in the s3 bucket url (`https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/mybucket/myobject.json`)

I get the following error:

> Error parsing parameter '--documents': Blob values must be a path to a file.

I have also gone through the error log file and the documentation for Amazon CloudSearch but I am not able to resolve the issue.

I have given all read write permissions access in Amazon S3 bucket and Amazon CloudSearch Domain. I am also using the latest version of AWS CLI .

I would really appreciate it if someone can help me regarding this.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?